# How do I get and set ag-grid state?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

How can I obtain and re-set the state of an ag-grid table? I mean, which columns are being show, in what order, with what sorting and filtering, etc.

**Update**: getColumnState and setColumnState seem to be close to what I want, but I cannot figure out the callbacks in which I should save and restore the state. I tried restoring it in onGridReady but when the actual rows are loaded, I lose the state.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the flow of your application, I think we'll need that in order to answer where you should 'restore the state'. What is happening between saving a state and restoring a state?

Comment: @Pablo do you have any sample code?

Comment: **Warning** Automatic aggregation when user set grouped will stop working after setColumnState

Comment: Pls help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65018177/ag-grid-community-infinite-row-model-for-server-side-pagination-community-free/65040658#65040658

Answer (score 20):

There is a very specific example on their website providing details for what you are trying to do: [javascript-grid-column-definitions](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/#column-api-example)

```js
function saveState() {
    window.colState = gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState();
    window.groupState = gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnGroupState();
    window.sortState = gridOptions.api.getSortModel();
    window.filterState = gridOptions.api.getFilterModel();
    console.log('column state saved');
}
```

and for restoring:

```js
function restoreState() {
    gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnState(window.colState);
    gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnGroupState(window.groupState);
    gridOptions.api.setSortModel(window.sortState);
    gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(window.filterState);
    console.log('column state restored');
}
```

Comment: If you want to save state whenever something changes, you can add event handlers to your grid options like this:
         onSortChanged: () => { saveState() },
         onFilterChanged: () => { saveState() },
         onColumnResized: () => { saveState() },
         onColumnMoved: () => { saveState() }

Answer (score 12):

I believe you are looking for [this page of the Docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/?framework=javascript#gsc.tab=0). This describes the column api and what functions are available to you. The functions that are of most relevance would be:

- `getAllDisplayedColumns()` - used to show what columns are able to be rendered into the display. Due to virtualization there may be some columns that aren't rendered to the DOM quite yet, iff you want only the columns rendered to the DOM then use `getAllDisplayedVirtualColumns()` - both functions show the order as they will be displayed on the webpage

  - The `Column` object that is returned from these functions contains sort and filter attributes for each of the columns.

I believe that all you need would be available to you from that function which would be called like this `gridOptions.columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns()`

Other functions which might be useful:

- Available from [`gridOptions.columnApi`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/?framework=javascript#gsc.tab=0):

  - `getColumnState()` - returns objects with less detail than the above funciton - only has: aggFunc, colId, hide, pinned, pivotIndex, rowGroupIndex and width
  - `setColumnState(columnState)` - this allows you to set columns to hidden, visible or pinned, `columnState` should be what is returned from `getColumnState()`
- Available from [`gridOptions.api`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/?framework=javascript#gsc.tab=0):

  - `getSortModel()` - gets the current sort model
  - `setSortModel(model)` - set the sort model of the grid, `model` should be the same format as is returned from `getSortModel()`
  - `getFilterModel()` - gets the current filter model
  - `setFilterModel(model)` - set the filter model of the grid, `model` should be the same format as is returned from `getFilterModel()`

There are other functions that are more specific, if you only want to mess with pinning a column you can use `setColumnPinned` or for multiple columns at once use `setColumnsPinned` and more functions are available from the linked pages of the AG-Grid docs

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know in which callback I should be restoring the state to the grid?

Comment: @pupeno for column state restoring, you can use gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnState(colState); in onGridReady() event

Answer (score 7):

The `gridReady` event should do what you need it to do. What I suspect is happening is your filter state is being reset when you update the grid with data - you can alter this behaviour by setting `filterParams: {newRowsAction: 'keep'}`

This can either by set by column, or set globally with `defaultColDef`.

Here is a sample configuration that should work for you:

```js
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFilter: true,
    onGridReady: function () {
        gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(filterState);
        gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnState(colState);
        gridOptions.api.setSortModel(sortState);
    },
    defaultColDef: {
        filterParams: {newRowsAction: 'keep'}
    }
};
```

I've created a plunker here that illustrates how this would work (note I'm restoring state from hard code strings, but the same principle applies): https://plnkr.co/edit/YRH8uQapFU1l37NAjJ9B . The `rowData` is set on a timeout 1 second after loading

Comment: The problem with the gridReady event is that it fires *after* the initial grid render. Applying column state on grid ready will first show the default column state, then an animation to the applied column state (i.e. columns size and position changing). This is disturbing for end users.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the filter values you may use 
    filterParams: {newRowsAction: 'keep'}

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach.  It simply involves creating a wrapper function with the same API as instantiating the agGrid.

A few things of interest in this function

- saves/loads to local storage
- makes use of the `addEventListener` that becomes available to the `options` object once it is passed in to the `Grid` function.
- attaches to the `onGridReady` callback of the `options` object without erasing what may already be defined.

usage:

```
newAgGrid(document.getElementById('my-grid'), options);
    
static newAgGrid(element, options) {
    const ls = window.localStorage;
    const key = `${location.pathname}/${element.id}`;
    const colStateKey = `${key}colstate`;
    const sortStateKey = `${key}sortState`;
    function saveState(params) {
        if (ls) {
            ls.setItem(colStateKey, JSON.stringify(params.columnApi.getColumnState()));
            ls.setItem(sortStateKey, JSON.stringify(params.api.getSortModel()));
        }
    }
    function restoreState(params) {
        if (ls) {
            const colState = ls.getItem(colStateKey);
            if (colState) {
                params.columnApi.setColumnState(JSON.parse(colState));
            }
            const sortState = ls.getItem(sortStateKey)
            if (sortState) {
                params.api.setSortModel(JSON.parse(sortState));
            }
        }
    }
    // monitor the onGridReady event.  do not blow away an existing handler
    let existingGridReady = undefined;
    if (options.onGridReady) {
        existingGridReady = options.onGridReady;
    }
    options.onGridReady = function (params) {
        if (existingGridReady) {
            existingGridReady(params);
        }
        restoreState(params);
    }
    // construct grid
    const grid = new agGrid.Grid(element, options);
    // now that grid is created, add in additional event listeners
    options.api.addEventListener("sortChanged", function (params) {
        saveState(params);
    });
    options.api.addEventListener("columnResized", function (params) {
        saveState(params);
    });
    options.api.addEventListener("columnMoved", function (params) {
        saveState(params);
    });
    return grid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of AG Grid v31, it now has support for loading/saving of grid state via a single combined object. See the AG-1535 feature in their changelog https://ag-grid.com/changelog/.

Reference: https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-state

Getting the state on any change:

```
function onStateUpdated(event: StateUpdatedEvent<IOlympicData>): void {
  console.log("State updated", event.state);
}
```

Getting the state right before the grid is destroyed:

```
function onGridPreDestroyed(event: GridPreDestroyedEvent<IOlympicData>): void {
  console.log("Grid state on destroy (can be persisted)", event.state);
}
```

Setting the initial state:

```
const gridOptions: GridOptions<IOlympicData> = {
  initialState: {}, // <=== Set initial state here
  onGridPreDestroyed: onGridPreDestroyed,
  onStateUpdated: onStateUpdated,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use `useRef()` to refer `<AgGridReact>` element to access getColumn and setColumn state in following way.

```
const GridRef = useRef()

GridRef.current.columnApi.getColumnState() //  get Column state value
GridRef.current.columnApi.setColumnState() //  set Column state value

<AgGridReact
   enableFilter={true}
   rowStyle={rowStyle}
   ref={GridRef}
></AgGridReact>
```

Answer (score -2):

The following needs to be done.

Include a div for the grid in your html

```
<div id="myGrid" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

On the js side

```
//initialize your grid object
var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');



//Define the columns options and the data that needs to be shown
        var gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: [
                {headerName: 'Name', field: 'name'},
                {headerName: 'Role', field: 'role'}
            ],
            rowData: [
                {name: 'Niall', role: 'Developer'},
                {name: 'Eamon', role: 'Manager'},
                {name: 'Brian', role: 'Musician'},
                {name: 'Kevin', role: 'Manager'}
            ]
        };

//Set these up with your grid
        new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
```

Check this pen out for more features. https://codepen.io/mrtony/pen/PPyNaB . Its done with angular