# AG Grid Layout questions

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to let users modify the look and feel of the grid as much as posible. So i implemented a back end where i for now save some of the custom settings per user like which column he like to show or hide. Now i want to be able to also save the folowing.

1. Column Width ( Is there a way to fire an event which gets me the colid as well as the new size in px or in case the user selected autosize that value is now autosize )
2. Column Order ( I am looking for an event which is fired once user drags a column to a new spot in grid. I am looking for colid and the new position so i can save the move to my backend)
3. Save complete layout ( Is there a function i can call to get the complete current layout of the grid so i can save it ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [grid events ag-Grid docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/), which describe several column related events. 
It should help you with point 1 (columnResized) and point 2 (columnMoved).To get new width on column resized you can use gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState().

Point 3 is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811020/how-do-i-get-and-set-ag-grid-state).